# Is it possible to specify what to return for certain arguments in Jasmine's spyOn()?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

Jasmine has a `spyOn` function but it only seems to have two arguments - the object, and the function name to call:

```
spyOn(foo, 'getBar').andReturn(745);
```

So for example, if I call `foo.getBar()` I should get 745.

I'm just wondering, what if I have a unit test that wants to mock two different calls to `getBar` with two different parameters returning two different results.

e.g. say I want to mock the below results, how could I achieve the following?

```
getBar(1) = 700  
getBar(2) = 500
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `andCallFake` to accomplish this:

```
spyOn(foo, 'getBar').andCallFake(function(n) {
  if (n === 1) {
    return 700;
  } else if (n === 2) {
    return 500;
  }

  throw "Invalid input";
});
```